# Remove attributes with missing values exceeding a given threshold in WEKA

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, feature-selection, preprocessing, weka

I imported csv file into WEKA, i have features that have missing value that has missing value percentage of 70% or above, i want to remove these features by weka or also sort that features by missing value percentage desc and then remove some features manually.

How can i do that? i'm new to machine learning and WEKA.